# Condition for continuity of bilinear form

Tags: continuity, bilinear-form

In my numeric script there is a unproved theorem, saying that a bilinear form $a \colon V\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ on a normed vector space $V$ is continuous if and only if

$$|a(v,w)| \leq c \, \|v\| \, \|w\|$$
holds for all $v,w\in V$ for some $c > 0$.

My first question is: what is ment by a continuous bilinearform? Is it according to the norm $\| (v,w) \| := \max \{ \|v\| , \|w\| \}$ (which is equivalent to $ \|(v,w)\| = \|v\| + \|w\|$) ?

If so, then I agree that such a bilinear form is continuous but I don't see that a continuous bilinear form is bounded as above. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: If $a$ is continuous, there is an $\delta$-neighborhood of the origin on which $a$ is bounded by $1$. Rescaling, we can see $a$ is bounded on unit ball around the origin. Can you see how that implies boundedness as in your question?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś If I could show that a is bounded by 1 in an $\delta$-neigborhood, than I belive it is easy to show that a is bounded by 1 on the whole space $V$. Because rescaling $v$ and $w$ on both sides just cancels out. Therefore, I dont think it is true that a is bounded by 1 near the $\delta$-neigborhood.

Comment: How does rescaling "on both sides" cancels out? $a(\alpha u,\beta v) = \alpha\beta\, a(u, v)$.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś $$|a (\alpha v ,\beta w)| \leq c || \alpha v|| ||\beta w||$$ is equivalent to   $$|a (v ,w)| \leq c ||  v|| || w|| $$.

Comment: Indeed it is. I'm sorry, but I really cannot see how that implies $a$ is bounded. We have $\left|a(u,v)\right|<C$ for $\|u\|,\|v\|\leq 1$, and rescaling gives us 
$$
\left|a(u,v)\right|<C\|u\|\|v\|
$$
No cancellation whatsoever.

Comment: And by the way, if there was no neighborhood of the origin on which $a$ is bounded by 1, $a$ would be discontinuous, as $a(0,0)=0$.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś Ok now I understand it - sorry, with bounded I thought you meant the following definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator. Do you want to post your answer so I can check it or shall I delete my question?

Comment: Sure, I'll post an answer. No need to delete question, I think it's valuable and reasonable.

Comment: Can you prove boundedness of the bilinear form without continuity?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat the above theorem shows a bilinear form is bounded if and only if its continuous. So if you have a bilinearform and its not given that its continuous, then it might not be bounded. Is that your question?

Comment: @Adam I think it does, but if I understand my tutorial sheet correctly, I have to prove it without knowing if it's continuous, that's why I'm confused: https://gyazo.com/21917d3727c4afb2d069b9fd47c989ba

Comment: @TheCodingWombat in your exersice sheet your vector space is of finite dimension. Every linear map on a finite space is continuous.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assume $a$ is continuous at the origint. Since $a(0,0)=0$, by definition of continuity, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\left|a(u,v)\right|<1$ for any $\|u\|,\|v\|\leq\delta$ (here I assume maximum norm). Thus, for any $u,v$ we have
$$
\left|a(u,v)\right|=
\left|a\left(\frac{\|u\|}{\delta}\,\frac{\delta u}{\|u\|}, \frac{\|v\|}{\delta}\,\frac{\delta v}{\|v\|}\right)\right|=
\delta^{-2}\|u\|\|v\|
\left|a\left(\frac{\delta u}{\|u\|}, \frac{\delta v}{\|v\|}\right)\right|<\delta^{-2}\|u\|\|v\|
$$
since $\delta\,u/\|u\|$, $\delta\, v/\|v\| \leq \delta$. Hence, $a$ is bounded.

Comment: So this also assumes we have the norm $\| (v,w) \| := \max \{ \|v\| , \|w\| \}$ on $V \times V$, right?

Comment: Yes, although with slight adjustments it will work for any equivalent norm on the product space.