# continuity of bilinear

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $B: E\times F\rightarrow G$ be a continuous bilinear map of normed spaces, where $\|(e,f)\| = \|e\| _E+\|f\|_F$.

Show that $\dfrac{\|B(e,f)\|}{\|(e,f)\|} \rightarrow 0$ as $(e,f) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Do you know a bilinear map is continuous iff it is bounded?

Comment: @VincentBoelens I am not sure whether you are saying $||B(e,f)||\le  C||e|| $ for a fixed $f$ and $||B(e,f)||\le  C||f|| $ for a fixed $e$?  If you mean $||B(e,f)|| \le C||e|| ||f||$, I wanna know how to prove?THX

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808983/condition-for-continuity-of-bilinear-form


see the answer

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Do you see how to use it to prove the statement?

Comment: @VincentBoelens YES, thx BRO.  I was not familiar with the definition of continuous bilinear map, but now I know. Very grateful