# Continuity of the linear operator $A:V\to V'$ induced by the bilinear continuous form $a:V\times V\to{\bf R}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $(\ ,)$ and norm $\|\cdot\|$. Suppose $a:V\times V\to{\bf R}$ is a bilinear continuous form. One can then define $A:V\to V'$ with $A(u)=\xi_u$ where $\xi_u(v)=a(u,v)$ for all $v\in V$. One can show by checking the definition that $A$ is linear.

> **Question**: how to show that $A$ is continuous?

---

Suppose $u_n\to u$ in $V$. I end up with showing the estimate 
$$
\sup_{v\in V, \|v\|=1}|a(u-u_n,v)|<\epsilon. 
$$
For each $v$, by the continuity of $a$, one has for some constant $M_v$, 
$$
|a(u-u_m,v)|\leq M_v\cdot \|u-u_m\|\tag{*}
$$
But I don't see how to get a bound for $\{M_v:\|v\|=1\}$ so that (*) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous bilinear is equivalent to $\| a(u,v)\|\leq C\|u\|\|v\|$.

You have $\|A(u)\|=sup_{\|x\|=1}\| a(u,x)\|\leq C\|u\|$.

[Condition for continuity of bilinear form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808983/condition-for-continuity-of-bilinear-form)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you show  the first sentence?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808983/condition-for-continuity-of-bilinear-form

Answer (score 0):

Since $a$ is continuous, for all $u,v\in V$ we have
$$
|A(u)(v)|=|a(u,v)|\le \|a\|\cdot\|u\|\cdot\|v\|.
$$
Therefore
$$
\sup_{\|v\|=1}\dfrac{|A(u)(v)|}{\|v\|}\le \|a\|\cdot\|u\|,
$$
i.e. for each $u\in A$, $A(u)$ is continuous and $\|A(u)\|\le \|a\|\cdot\|u\|$ for all $u\in V$. It follows that
$$
\sup_{\|u\|=1}\|A(u)\|\le \|a\|,
$$
i.e.
$A$ is continuous and $\|A\|\le \|a\|$.